# Game Submit Score

Tags: game-development

I have a simple 2048 game, and each time a user plays the game, gets a score, they have a button to submit this score. The user is identifiable.

However, how do I know if the user actually played the game? Some users may inspect traffic and know the API endpoint, then use this API to submit a score without playing the game.

Is there any mechanism/methods to stop this from happening?

Comment: If the game runs 100% in the client, you have no way of actually check that.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).

Answer (score 1):

There is, but nothing simple, we are near the POW problem in block chains.

The first idea that comme in minds is that the server provide the seed that will generate the 'random' position and value of the number that are added after each move, then instead of pushing the score, the client have to push the actual moves, all of them, so the game can be replayed and checked server side.